# Javascript Proxy: prevent any further properties to get called when a property does not exist on a multi level object

Tags: javascript, node.js, modularity

### Context

while working on a modular architecture, I try to make as much "weak" dependencies as possible. For that purpose I use a "bridgeService" that handle all inter-module interactions.

### Problem

I would use the bridgeService as follow:

```js
// in moduleA.js
bridgeService.moduleB.functionA();
```

But if moduleB does not exists this wil throw an error `cannot read property functionA of undefined` or `bridgeService.moduleB.functionA is not a function`.

### Expectations

**My will is that it fails softly. If any of the properties in the property chain is missing, this will log a warning, return `null` or `false` AND prevent all further properties to get called.**

### Actual code

Here is what I got at the moment:

```js
// Proxy handler
const safeNotInstanciatedWarningProxy = {
    get: function (object, prop) {
        if (prop in object) return object[prop];
        else {
            console.warn(`${prop} not defined`);
            return new Proxy({}, safeNotInstanciatedWarningProxy);
        }
    }
}

const bridgeService = new Proxy({}, safeNotInstanciatedWarningProxy)
```

This will never throw the first `cannot read property functionA of undefined` error. But when the last function get called, I can't get rid of the `is not a function` error.

Is there a way to achieve exactly what I want in javascript ? If not, what would be the best alternative ?

Thanks for your lights

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want but if you use Node >=v14 you could give [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) a try.

Comment: Not a bad idea, this will lead to `bridgeService.moduleB?.functionA?();`

Comment: Yea, but with `?.` instead of `?` only, between `functionA` and `()`. Otherwise it's probably treated as ternary

Comment: Your `safeNotInstanciatedWarningProxy` is a function that returns a handler object, but you never call that function! Just drop the `() =>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't get rid of the is not a function error.

You can make the proxy wrap a function instead:

```js
return new Proxy(() => {
    console.warn("… and is not a function");
}, safeNotInstanciatedWarningProxy);
```

Of course, this will fail once your modules expects the methods to return something.

[Here is an example on codePen](https://codepen.io/seb-rom-o/pen/dyGwzXO?editors=0011)

Comment: Not a bad idea. However, I will not always know when it's gonna be a function in the property stack. It can be either `a.b.c()` or  `a.b.c.d.e()`. The ideal will be this to work in both cases

Comment: Doesn't matter. They're all functions. `a.b.c` is a function and the proxy gives it a `.d` property. So are `b, `d` and `e` (and possibly even `a` itself).

Comment: In fact it works very well! I didn't exactly understand it at first sight. I have added a sample code to be more explicit.